# Document evaluate method Strict mode error

Tags: javascript

First, JavaScript is not my specialty and this is a former developers code I'm trying to fix.

I'm upgrading some IE code that needs to run on Edge, Chrome... and I'm getting an issue with the following code block:

```
XMLDocument.prototype.selectNodes = function(cXPathString, xNode) {
                if( !xNode ) { xNode = this; }
                var oNSResolver = this.createNSResolver(this.documentElement);
                var aItems = this.evaluate(cXPathString, xNode, oNSResolver, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
                var aResult = [];
                for( var i = 0; i < aItems.snapshotLength; i++) {
                    aResult[i] = aItems.snapshotItem(i);
                }
                return aResult;
            }
```

The error I'm getting is:
*Exception: TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them at Function.*...

From what I've read I think it has something to do with the use of 'this' in the function or 'callee' is not defined in Strict mode? I tried to replace 'this' with document, which is the DOM Document but that didn't fix it.

I'm probably way off so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott.

Comment: At which line are you getting that error? Please provide the stack trace, or even better a [mcve]

Comment: You'll get that error when literally accessing `.caller`, `.callee` or `.arguments` somewhere. The use of `this` has nothing to do with it. The exception doesn't appear to come from the code snippet you posted.

Comment: @Bergi I think you may be right in that it's not the evaluate code. What threw me was when I open the Developer Tools in Edge and add a breakpoint to the line, the this.evaluate line shows with a red line under it and an error symbol at the end. When 
 I hover over 'evaluate' and click on the ... after 'arguments' I see the error message listed above. That made me think that was where the error was.